# Yii2, нужна помощь в написании метода для api

Tags: php, yii2

Есть модели StickerPack и Sticker. Между ними связь один ко многим. Так вот, как сделать так чтобы мне  при возвращении списка StickerPack, внутри самого StickerPack возвращалось 5 Sticker'ов.

Answer (score 0):

[Жадная выгрузка](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading) должна вам подойти, к примеру если вы выводите список паков:

```
$packs = StickerPack::find()
    ->with('stickers')
    ->limit(20)
    ->all();
```

Вместе с выборкой с таблицы паков сразу же будет выборка данных с таблиц стикеров, и тогда вы получите сразу список стикеров внутри объекта `StickerPack`, но зависит ещё от того как вы отдаете эти данные.

Comment: чет не. говорит нет никакого отношения

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов потому что я его сам придумал, вы называете так как у вас называется реляция

Comment: я извиняюсь за, может быть, глупость. Я начинающий разработчик. Не подскажите тогда, как эту реляцию организовать. Сейчас, для связи таблиц, я использую всего один метод: `  public function getStickers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sticker::className(), ['itemId' => 'id']);
    }`

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов странно, реляция вроде описана правильно, у вас данные не выводит или пишет ошибку при выборке?

Comment: Exception вылетает

Comment: Видите ли, скорее всего ошибка в чем то глупом. Типа где нибудь, что нибудь не дописал ...

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов ну скорее всего так и есть, если бы вы ещё писали что именно происходит то давно бы уже решили вопрос, а так вытягивать по слову надо

Comment: вообще это все что есть. Типа две модели и метод getStickers() описанный в модели StickerPack. Нужно наверное описать эту связь где то еще, в fields() может быть

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов exception какой?

Comment: "name": "Exception",
    "message": "app\\models\\StickerPack has no relation named \"sticker\".",

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов stickers же, а не sticker

Comment: блин точно. но теперь новая проблема : ` "name": "Invalid Configuration",
    "message": "The \"query\" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\\db\\Query or its subclasses.",`

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов это уже что-то с вашим запросом или кодом не так, простой запрос с моего примера должен отработать, так что это уже выходит за пределы вашего вопроса, а то мы тут и так нафлудили